# My toilet sounds like an angry goose

Tags: plumbing, toilet, sounds

My toilet is making strange sounds when it's flushed. I suspect something in the fill valve is vibrating. [Here is a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g9IFQz8c4S9eqVjUCpHLyC9Ob6vLK7i4/view?usp=sharing) of it. It's pretty intermittent and sometimes it's longer and louder than that.

Do I just need to replace the fill valve?

---

### Update

It's definitely something in/on/around the fill valve. While inspecting the flapper today I drained the toilet and upon refilling it I discovered that I can reliably recreate the sound by filling the tank up when empty. Here is a [video of it](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bUPUhJdZ0S2FJHN7N4DbrH0nATPZqgcH/view?usp=sharing).

I tried it several times and the sound is definitely coming from the left where the fill valve is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be the fill valve. Once I replaced it, everything quieted down.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the flapper might not be sealing initially. As it fills, the water pushes on it and completes the seal. It's probably slightly warped on one side (given the light-pink color, this flapper looks faded, meaning it's probably old). You can verify this by pulling the valve off and inspecting the edge

Comment: did you mean to call the faded pink **flapper** a fill valve ? The fill valve is the bluish thing in the left side of the tank.

Comment: Agree that it could be the flapper.  The fill valve is already fully on for a second before the goose honk (you can see the water spray in the overflow tube), so I don't think it would be the fill valve.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Yep, teach me to drive-by answer